# LLVM Compiler can't find symbol __bridge with ARC turned on

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undeclared identifier __bridge on xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063644/undeclared-identifier-bridge-on-xcode)

I'm new to automatic reference counting in iOS 5.0 and converting an old project from manual memory management to ARC. Everything works fine (I turned ARC off for selected 3rd party libraries with the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag) except for Apples Reachability class. I have downloaded an ARC'ified version of Reachability here

https://gist.github.com/1182373

which seems to work fine for a number of people.

I do get the following compiler error:

```
use of undeclared identifier '__bridge' [3]
         NSCAssert([(__bridge NSObject*) info isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");
```

I had an older (non-ARC) version of Reachability in my project before and compiled it with the -fno-objc-arc flag before. I have removed the compiler flag, cleaned and compiled but keep getting the abovementioned error. When removing the __bridge symbol, I get the following error as expected

```
error: cast to 'NSObject *' of a non-Objective-C to an Objective-C pointer is disallowed with Automatic Reference Counting [4]
     NSCAssert([(NSObject*) info isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");
```

so you can see that ARC is indeed turned on. I use XCode 4.2 (build 4D5031b).

I'd appreciate any insights you might have to offer! Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Georg

Comment: Hi He. I did read the post you linked to as well as the post that post linked to. However, I didn't find a solution there. Would you have any idea what went wrong in my case?

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem. It seems as if Xcode somehow remembered the -fno-objc-arc flag I've set for the old version of Reachability, even after I replaced it with the new, arc'ified version. The problem did not occur when I started with a completely empty project.

Comment: given the solution to the problem, I don't see that the root cause for my problem was not the same one as that covered in the post that was linked as a possible duplicate. Shouldn't we reopen this issue?